# python program transpose of a matrix

Tags: linux, python-3.x

A two dimensional matrix can be represented in Python row-wise, as a list of lists: each inner list represents one row of the matrix. For instance, the matrix

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

would be represented as `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

The transpose of a matrix makes each row into a column. For instance, the transpose of the matrix above is

```
1  4  
2  5
3  6
```

Write a Python function transpose(m) that takes as input a two dimensional matrix using this row-wise representation and returns the transpose of the matrix using the same representation.

Answer (score 1):

this is my go-to method (using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)):

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

mat_t = list(zip(*mat))
print(mat_t)
# [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

caveat: you get `tuple`s as rows (may need to convert that to `list`s). that could be achieved with

```
mat_t = list(list(row) for row in zip(*mat))
print(mat_t)
# [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

written as a function this would be:

```
def transpose(mat):
    return list(list(row) for row in zip(*mat))
```

Comment: what is not working? could you be a bit more specific? (the output in present in my answer was generated from python 3.5 . so it *is* working).

Answer (score 1):

As you have specified [**linux**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag, here's short *datamash* one-liner:

```
datamash -W transpose <file
```

The output:

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/

---

As for *Python* solution, I would use [***numpy***](http://www.numpy.org/) module which is the best to work with matrices and numerical data:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
transposed = a.transpose()

print(transposed)
```

The output:

```
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```